# Laravel 6 - View the data of the comparison statement in if condition

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-6

The title might sound confusing but this what I want to achieve in displaying the data.

I have a table **tbl_employee** which has a **supervisor_id**. The structure would be

- senior manager
- manager
- team leader

I am using this syntax

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-dark">
  <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Department Name</th>
    <th>Supervisor ID</th></th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>

  @foreach($getEmployee as $id => $employee)
    @if(Auth::user()->id == $employee->supervisor_id)
  <tr>
    <td>{{++$id}}</td>
    <td>{{$employee->first_name}}</td>
    <td>{{$employee->supervisor_id}}</td>
  </tr>
    @endif
  @endforeach
</table>
```

**Controller**

```
public function create() {
$getEmployee = EmployeeModel::all();
$getDepartment = DepartmentModel::pluck('department_name', 'id');

$getSupervisor = EmployeeModel::select
(DB::raw("CONCAT(last_name,', ',first_name,' ',middle_name,' ',COALESCE(extension_name,'')) AS full_name"),'id')
   ->pluck('full_name', 'id');

$getHR = EmployeeModel::select
(DB::raw("CONCAT(last_name,', ',first_name,' ',middle_name,' ',COALESCE(extension_name,'')) AS full_name"),'id')
   ->where('position_id', 1)
   ->pluck('full_name', 'id');

return view('EmployeeView.add', compact('getDepartment', 'getSupervisor', 'getHR', 'getEmployee'));
  }
```

I logged-in a senior manager account and I was able to see managers who has a supervisor_id of the senior manager. Now I also wanted to see team leaders who has a supervisor_id of a manager under the senior manager. I am quite confused on how to do a query.

Comment: Can you provide code from controller and model where you defined relations?

Comment: Hello! I'm very sorry for the late reply. I have now posted my controller.